# Cannot find a Google App Script I deployed as a web app

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I find a Google App Script web app I deployed and modify it?  It does not appear in my drive.  Perhaps I didn't save it.  Does it persist or disappear eventually?  Is there somewhere that list all deployed web apps?  If so, I have been unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If your webapp is recent, simply replace "exec" at the end of the url with "edit" (without quotes) and you'll get the script editor opened on your script.

(Very old webapp have a different structure but it changed quite a long time ago so I guess you're not concerned with that.)

Answer (score 0):

No. There is nothing like deployed webapps list. if u didn't save, u can't get it back even though you had deployed it. Make a try to open that script with the url available in your browser's history.